# custom pause option value in bxslider on each slide

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I have applied bxslider on `ul` element. But i want to have different pause attribute value for each slide.

```
slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    speed:500,
    pause:5000,
    onSlideBefore: function(){
    },
    onSlideAfter: function(){
    }
});
```

Inside `onSlideBefore` or `onSlideAfter` i want to set pause value of the next (if code is inside `onSlideBefore`) or current slide (if code is inside `onSlideAfter`) so that each image slide will be having their own transition value.

Appreciate your help in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem with below code. Not sure if this is the correct way to do so. Try it out if it helps you.
I added a new public method inside `jquery.bxslider.min.js` as below.

```
n.setPause = function (t) {
    if(s.settings.auto){
        clearInterval(s.interval);
        s.interval = setInterval(function () {
        s.settings.autoDirection=="next"?n.goToNextSlide() : n.goToPrevSlide()}, t)
    }
};
```

where, t is the milliseconds for each individual image slide.

In my JSP, i added `onSlideAfter` function where $slider is the jQuery element on which bxslider is applied.

```
onSlideAfter: function(){
    $slider.setPause(current image pause in milliseconds);
}
```